# Twitter sentiment prediction using Naive Bayes in Spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have done model training using Spark MLlib and want to use it in Spark streaming. Is there any way other than PMML model export. I think PMML model export is not yet developed (see [SPARK-8546](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8546) ).

Is there any other way possible wherein i can do prediction in Spark streaming?

I am doing Twitter Sentiment Analysis and wanted to use Naive Bayes because it brings low latency.

Comment: Sentiment prediction on tweet isn't that accurate, just so that you know...

Comment: Yes that's correct. So now I am not particularly concern about the accuracy but about the latency (when prediction happens in Spark Streaming).

Comment: If your model is trained before hand, their shouldn't be much latency.

Comment: Thanks thats very assuring. Also as stated in the question, how to load a model in spark streaming? Is it same as that in Spark e.g for SVM it is sameModel = SVMModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")